# Modman - dealing with template files spread across multiple modules

Tags: module, magento-1

I use modman for development and will typically have a core module in the client namespace for the heavy lifting of the customisations such as the theme, locale base install/upgrade scripts etc.

Additionally, for any specific customisations to core code i will create a custom local module in the client namespace and then extend the relevant Magento module.

My modman directory may look similar to this:

```
ClientName_Core
ClientName_Catalog
ClientName_Newsletter
ClientName_Cms
```

The core module will hold the theme and skin to keep all of that contained in 1 place.  However, this causes a problem for me.

If one of the specific extended modules needs to create custom template files then they would be symlinked into the already symlinked design directory from the Core module.  It then gets a bit messy.

How do other developers out there deal with this situation and organise their modman directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do also use modman, but only put "re-useable" modules into the modman folder.
A Module ClientName_Core would therefor not exist in the modman-folder, but directly in the main source under app/code/local in the git repository.
This prevents us from having the problem you explained (creating symlinks in the already sym-linkes folder).

Really Client-specific developments are kept in app/code/local in the main git repository, Modules which can be re-used are created as modman modules and put into the repository via git submodules.